# Reduce a range of values to a list in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table with printer names and the model numbers of the toner and drums which they use. I'm looking for a way to generate a single column list from this range of values, excluding blank cells. Below is the table:

[image]

I'd like to end up with a list of values as such:

```
MX-C30NT-B
MX-C30NT-C
MX-C30NT-M
MX-C30NT-Y
MX-C30DR
MX-C30HB
MX-C30NV-B
MX-C30NV-C
MX-C30NV-M
MX-C30NV-Y
...
```

I know in Excel I can use an array formula to accomplish this, but array formulas don't seem to be as robust in Sheets. Is there a formula which will perform this conversion?

Comment: What have you tried already? Personally I find arrayformulas way more intuitive and easy to use in Google Spreadsheets.

Comment: Are you after a single list for each row or a list of all rows?  I am understanding you are looking for columns **B Ink** to **Y Developer**, correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combining nonempty cells in columns E-M into a single column, ignoring the header row:

```
=filter({E2:E; F2:F; G2:G; H2:H; I2:I; J2:J; K2:K; L2:L; M2:M}, len({E2:E; F2:F; G2:G; H2:H; I2:I; J2:J; K2:K; L2:L; M2:M}))
```

The first argument is just a bunch of column stacked; the `filter` excludes empty ones. Note that the second `{...}` construct is identical to the first, it's a copy-paste.

Comment: That was spot on, thanks! Any chance you'd be willing to briefly explain the use of curly braces and semi-colons? I'm about to Google it, but I'm sure it'd be great for posterity.

Comment: This is [array notation in Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)

Comment: Excellent @zaq!