# Converting a rectangular range to a row or column representation in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I need a way in Google Sheets to turn rectangular range to a row or column representation. For example, suppose we have the following two-by-tree range (i.e. B2:D3):

```
  A B C D E F G H
1 . . . . . . . .
2 . X X X . . . .
3 . Y Y Y . . . .
4 . . . . . . . .
5 . . . . . . . .
6 . . . . . . . .
```

If this range were to be converted to a row anchored in B5, we would get this:

```
  A B C D E F G H
1 . . . . . . . .
2 . X X X . . . .
3 . Y Y Y . . . .
4 . . . . . . . .
5 . X X X Y Y Y .
6 . . . . . . . .
```

I have come across complex ways of doing this such as using =filter() as in [Reduce a range of values to a list in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41599923/reduce-a-range-of-values-to-a-list-in-google-sheets) but each of these solutions requires the input to be specified row-by-row or column-by-columnn. So ideally I need something like =rangeToList(B2:D3) to produce what we see in B5:G5.

Thanks much.

Comment: seems like an XY problem.  http://xyproblem.info/ Can you explain more about the "why" you want to do that?

Comment: The constraint in the question has to do with what my audience will know at the time I need the functionality. I am using spreadsheets as a sandbox to illustrate ideas in an entry mathematics course. To explain the Cartesian Product of three sets (say A x B x C), the A x B product in the form of a table will have to be turned into a list form to calculate ( A x B ) x C. I am trying to get away with the least set of Google Sheets features to do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be too simplistic, but the data can be re-arranged using existing functions like this:

```
=transpose(flatten(B2:D3))
```

[image]

Comment: It should be mentioned that FLATTEN() is an undocumented function discovered recently by a user in the Google Product Forums (March 2020).  It's believed it is intended to remain "hidden" in the back end of the sheets programming, but there is no guarantee that the formula will continue to work indefinitely.  Here is a demo sheet made by PE MattKing when it was discovered. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/196NDPUZ-p2sPiiiYlYsJeHD6F_eJq7CWO_hP7rFqGpc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Tom Sharpe, you are my hero! MattKing, thanks for the heads up, I certainly hope they keep this =flatten() function in there.